# When can I "change variables" in thermodynamic configuration space?

Tags: thermodynamics, potential, coordinate-systems

Edit: This question has been asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305222/), but has not been answered directly as far as I can tell.

In Chapter 5 of Callen, a great deal of the motivation for introducing the Legendre transform (and thus, thermodynamic potentials) is so that intensive variables like $T,P,\mu$ can, in contexts where it's useful, be used as the independent variables. It was emphasized that the Legendre transform is a way of describing these systems in terms of intensive variables, *but without losing information* as would be the case if we simply inverted equations of state and replaced extensive variables by some intensive variables.

For example, it was discussed that, in writing $U = U(S,V,N)$ instead as (using the physicist's standard abuse of notation for different functions) $U = U(T,P,N)$ by elimination with $T = T(S,V,N)$ and $P = P(S,V,N)$, one loses information (turning the fundamental equation into a PDE). The Legendre transform (to $G = G(T,P,N)$) in this case lets us transform without losing information.

However, it seems that sometimes Callen nevertheless does the elimination that loses information, and I am trying to understand why this is valid. For example, in his discussion of adiabatic compression in Chapter 7.4 Callen writes (my commentary in bold)

> By differentiation, we can find the two equations of state $T = T(S, V, N)$ and $P = P(S, V, N)$ **[No problems here]**. By knowing the initial temperature and pressure, we can thereby find the initial volume and entropy **[No problems here either; we are simply solving two equations in two unknowns ($V_i$, S_i)]**. Elimination of $V$ between the two equations of state gives the temperature as a function of $S$, $P$, and $N$ **[Are we not losing information in this step?]**.

As he says in Chapter 5, does not the rewriting in terms of derivatives (intensive parameters) make our fundamental equation into a PDE? As Callen says, for $P = dY/dX$,

> From the analytical point of view the relation $Y = Y(P)$ is a first-order differential equation, and its integration gives $Y = Y(X)$ only to within an undetermined integration constant.

Does the resolution to this problem perhaps have something to do with it being acceptable to (sometimes?) "locally" invert, as has been done above? What are the rules here?

Comment: The point is that the Legendre transform by itself is a information conserving transformation. That is the point of doing Legendre transform, as opposed to just swapping variables. Simply think of Callen's paragraph as describing how you do Legendre transform.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I follow about the Legendre transform, I am asking about the other case (when we just swap in other variables).

Comment: Swapping will lose info; I think what Callen meant is to do Legendre transform, just worded badly.

Comment: But I am saying that in the examples in Chapter 7 Callen does *not* do a Legendre transform; he expresses $S$ in terms of $T,P,N$ for example. @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: I'll have to go home to take a look, but I do not see the point of you getting stuck in your reading by picking an uncharitable view of what he is doing, just because he is writing it badly. It would be more conducive for your reading if you read him charitably and interpret those as proper Legendre transforms, so that you can move on.

Comment: That is well taken, and I have indeed moved on to your point (Phase transitions in Chapter 8 ahead!). But I don't agree that this is simply an error or sloppy from Callen, as he does this substitution over and over, both in words and equations, and for various different quantities $S,T,P, etc.$. I think there's something here about. being able to locally invert but I am unable to make it precise or to understand when it's possible, and how information isn't lost. @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: There are a lot of red herrings around this subject, but the point is very simple. You never “lose information” by invertibly changing variables — you are always free to describe any quantity in terms of any reasonable set of variables.

Comment: The Legendre transformation does something very specific. If you have a function whose differential, in terms of some variable, is very simple, then its Legendre transform is a different function whose differential, in terms of the conjugate variable, is _also_ simple. A trivial example being that if $dU = -P dV$ then $dH = V dP$, which are both simple expressions. It’s not like $H$ is the only function related to $U$ that could possibly be defined. It’s just the most convenient one to consider in many contexts.

Comment: You could also freely write $dU = (\ldots) dP$ and this wouldn’t lose any information. What it would lose is convenience: there would not be a simple expression for $\ldots$ in terms of $V$ and $P$, while for $H$ there is.

Comment: Courant (CALCULUS OF VARIATIONS, page  55) writes that given the function $w=f(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ and the tangent plane $\xi_i=\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, $w = \sum_i x_i \xi_i -f$, then the variable $x_i$ can be eliminated if the determinant of the Hessian $det |\tfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}| \ne 0$, that is the Jacobian of $\xi_i$ is not zero, in which case we have $w=W(\xi_1,\xi_2,..,\xi_n)$. For all real processes $\delta^2 S > 0$, expressing the convexity of the entropy function and the associated determinant is not zero.

Comment: I should make clear that it is not just any change of variables, but a change of variables from a variable to a derivative with respect to that variable (e.g. $U(S,V,N) \to U(T,V,N)$). Does this change the discussion at all, @knzhou ?  That is, even assuming that for a function $y(x)$ $p(x) := dy/dx$ is invertible, do I not lose information in replacing $x$ with $p$ since I don't have an integration constant? Or is such an inversion permissible when I somehow tacitly "fix" that integration constant (and that is what Callen does)?

Comment: @hyportnex I believe you are giving the conditions for the applicability of a Legendre transform, no?

Comment: yes, exactly, the condition to have a variable replaced with its corresponding partial derivative  (except I should have written $\delta ^2 S <0$ , entropy is maximum, not minimum, in equilibrium). I interpreted your question asking for that condition. This is a local condition, and has no global significance. It may fail at phase transitions, for example, where the function may not have continuous 2nd derivative.

Comment: To clarify, my question is not about the requirements for a Legendre transform, but for a coordinate change directly to the intensive variables. Let me know if my question is unclear and I can restate. @hyportnex

Comment: If requirements for a "Legendre transform" is not the same as "coordinate change directly to the intensive variables" then I have no idea what your question is about.

Comment: In the above I talk about writing eg $U=U(T,V,N)$ (replacing $S$) rather than transforming to the free energy $F$. My question is how this is permitted given the discussion in Callen Chap 5 that such a transformation loses information. @hyportnex

Comment: I think what Callen means by the "sacrifice of some information" is that if you just use all the tangents (intensives) directly you lose *size* information; this is manifested in the Gibbs-Duhem equation that is zero and is scale invariant. This is indicated by fig 5.4.page 139, that the slopes cannot select the right one from the parallels defined  by the slopes. As long as you keep at least one extensive variable, e.g., total mass, the problem goes away.

Comment: @knzhou If you are willing to take a peek here one more time (before I accept the given answer) I would greatly appreciate it. I am still feeling like I am missing something.

Comment: It will all make sense once you put yourself in the shoes of a 19th century engineer with no calculators or computers, doing everything by hand with rulers and graph paper. An invertible transformation _never_ loses any information. But not all such transformations are _easy_ to invert with such primitive tools, while the Legendre transformation is. Unfortunately, the teaching of thermodynamics hasn't evolved much since 1850, so statements that made sense back then are a bit confusing today.

Comment: @knzhou I think you are missing a key point about Legendre's transformation. It has nothing to do with 19th-century math capability. The problem of losing information with a naive change of variables in the case the new variable is a partial derivative of the original fundamental equation is a real one and depends on the easily verifiable fact that if you know, say,  only $U(T,V,N)$ it is impossible to recover the  original $U(S,V,N)$ without introducing arbitrary functions of $V$ and $N$.  Try to recover the expression for entropy of an ideal gas from the knowledge that $U=cNk_BT$.

Comment: @hyportnex Callen's concept of  "sacrifice of some information"  has nothing to do with extensive or intensive variables. Indeed the problem would remain there even in the case of non-extensive Thermodynamics. Just playing with simple functions should be enough to make evident such a point.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 true as the referenced plot in Callen shows when replacing an arbitrary coordinate variable with the corresponding slope but here we were talking about thermodynamic variables and what happens with those substitutions, hence my comment.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main problem in understanding what Callen did on those pages depends on transforming a possibility into an obligation.

Indeed, if we want to change thermodynamic variables *keeping at the same time* the whole information contained in a fundamental thermodynamic function (like entropy, Massieu functions, or thermodynamic potentials), we must use Legendre transforms. However, in some cases, we do not need to have a reversible transform. In particular, if we do not lose the memory of the original fundamental equation, it is perfectly possible to perform any change of variables (provided it is mathematically well-defined).

For example, if we want to go from a description of a thermodynamic system in terms of the entropy and its natural variables ($S(U,V,N)$) to an equivalent description in terms of $T,V,N$, we have to introduce the Massieu potential
$$
\Phi (T,V,N)= S-\frac1TU.
$$
Even if we forget the original $S(U,V,N)$, the new function allows us to recover it.

However, there are situations where we are not interested in a new, equivalent description. For example, we may want to express the thermodynamic state $(U,V,N)$ in terms of other variables, say $(T,V,N)$. In such a case, we need to invert the function
$$
\frac1T =\left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right|_{V,N}(U,V,N)
$$
and we can give the entropy as a function of $(T,V,N)$.

Without the original fundamental equation, we cannot get it back without adding the missing information under the form of some arbitrary function. But if our goal is to assign an entropy to the state with a given value of $(T,V,N)$ that's enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am going to hold off on accepting for now, in case there are any other perspectives, but this makes sense to me.